# Отправка POST запроса с Кнопки

Tags: php, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите разобраться. Значит ситуация следующая

Есть форма которая отправляется по нажатию на кнопку. Появилась необходимость сделать подтверждение действия. А именно. Нажимаем на кнопку отправить, появляется модельное окно, (или как то по другому), в котором есть 2 кнопки Подтверждаю, Отказ. При нажатии подтвердить отправляется пост запрос в файл обработчик. И самое главное как это реализовать:
Пример модального окна

```html
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Выдать</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Заработна плата выдана.</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Отказ</button>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" value="Подтверждаю" onclick="sendRequest('post.php', 'test_var=x=4&y=5')" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: а чем не устраивают <form> и submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" onclick="return confirm('Подтверждаю');">
```

дешево и сердито

Comment: Примного благодарин за подсказу.